# Web View loads page for built application, but not test flight deployed version

Tags: ios, uiwebview

We've just been developing an update for our iOS application where we need to open up a web view and display a web page hosted on a 3rd party site.  This has worked locally when building directly to a device using xCode, the application works as expected; the web page loads and we can interact with it as expected.  However, if we build the application and deploy to test flight, on the same device the webview functionality no longer works.  Everything else works as expected but when the webview opens it just stays blank - the web page doesn't load/display.  It's the same device, the same code base and same 3rd party link, so the only difference is the provisioning profile we're using (dev vs ad-hoc).  Looking in application services I can't see any thing that looks like we should be setting (in fact our dev/ad-hoc provisioning profiles have the same settings).   We are looking to see if there is any event we can hook into to get more detail but the application isn't crashing.  Has anyone come across something similar before or point us in a direction/area that could help throw more light on the problem (might be searching for the wrong thing, but not found anything on google / stackoverflow).

Comment: Try putting a proxy between your app on the device and the internet to see whether it requests the web page at all, and if it does what response it gets (e.g. Charles - http://www.charlesproxy.com)

Comment: Thanks, yes we did try that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end this appears to be down to a difference in the execution of the code when built and when deployed (maybe deployed is faster).  We traced that all the relevant calls were being made using Charles proxy and looking in somme logging we had running on the web server.  To try and find out where the code was getting to we added "alert boxes" - with these in place both versions displayed the web page correctly (locally built and deployed through test flight).   As we couldn't leave the alert boxes in :) the solution was to move where we set up the web call and also to programmatically create the web view, rather than using one attached to the XIB.  Still haven't got to the bottom of what exactly was happening.

Comment: we too having same problem. Any solution you got for this?

Comment: @sairam I know it's not too much help, but trying to think back to this I don't think we ever got beyond identifying it was a timing issue and moving the code around to find out what worked for us.